# How to mention escape character in xml using JIBX

Tags: java, jibx

I need help with JIBX marshalling.

I have a String  "This is test <:test> this is test";

After marshalling this is getting converted to

```
<cus:street>This is test &lt;:test> This is test</cus:street>
```

Please suggest a solution how can I prevent the conversion of < to &lt from java code without making any changes in the schema.

### Customer.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:cus="http://www.trivadis.com/cdm/customer"
        targetNamespace="http://www.trivadis.com/cdm/customer"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
 <xsd:element name="customer" type="cus:CustomerType"/>
 <xsd:complexType name="CustomerType">
 <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:integer"/>
  <xsd:element name="firstName"  type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="lastName" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="address" type="cus:AddressType"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="AddressType">
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="zipCode" type="xsd:integer"/>
  <xsd:element name="country" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

### MarshallingTest.java

```
package com.trivadis.soa;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller;
import org.springframework.oxm.Unmarshaller;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.trivadis.cdm.customer.Address;
import com.trivadis.cdm.customer.Customer;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
//ApplicationContext will be loaded from "classpath:/com/trivadis/soa/PublisherTest-   context.xml"
@ContextConfiguration
public class MarshallingTest {

@Autowired
private Marshaller marshaller;
@Autowired
private Unmarshaller unmarshaller;

private static final String FILE_NAME = "G:/spring-oxm-jibx-sample/NewFile.xml";

@Test
public void testMarshalUnmarshalCustomer() throws Exception {
    Customer cust = null;
    Customer custRead = null;

    cust = new Customer();
    cust.setId(1);
    cust.setFirstName("Guido");
    cust.setLastName("Schmutz");

    Address adr = new Address();
    adr.setStreet("This is test <test> this is test");
    adr.setZipCode(3014);
    adr.setCity("Bern");
    adr.setCountry("Switzerland");

    cust.setAddress(adr);

    FileOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);
        marshaller.marshal(cust, new StreamResult(os));
    } finally {
        if (os != null) {
            os.close();
        }
    }

    FileInputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME);
        custRead = (Customer) this.unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(is));
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }

    Assert.assertEquals(cust.getId(), custRead.getId());
    Assert.assertEquals(cust.getFirstName(), custRead.getFirstName());
    Assert.assertEquals(cust.getLastName(), custRead.getLastName());
    //Assert.assertEquals(cust.getAddress().getStreet(), custRead.getAddress().getStreet());
    Assert.assertEquals(cust.getAddress().getZipCode(), custRead.getAddress().getZipCode());
    Assert.assertEquals(cust.getAddress().getCity(), custRead.getAddress().getCity());
    Assert.assertEquals(cust.getAddress().getCountry(), custRead.getAddress().getCountry());
}
}
```

### output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cus:customer xmlns:cus="http://www.trivadis.com/cdm/customer">
<cus:id>1</cus:id>
<cus:firstName>Guido</cus:firstName>
<cus:lastName>Schmutz</cus:lastName>
<cus:address>
    <cus:street>This is test &lt;test> this is test</cus:street>
    <cus:city>Bern</cus:city>
    <cus:zipCode>3014</cus:zipCode>
    <cus:country>Switzerland</cus:country>
</cus:address>
</cus:customer>
```

Comment: That is required for valid xml. If you left an unescaped `<`, the xml parser would assume that means an xml element is about to begin or end.

Comment: Thanks I get that but my requirement is as such to get a text like "This is test <Test> again test".

Comment: And when the xml is parsed the escape characters will be "unescaped" and turned back into the text you expect.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to achieve that?

Comment: Use an xml parser to parse the xml. This could be DOM, SAX, StAX, JAXB, JAXP, pretty much anything.

Comment: I am using JIBX parser. The output mentioned in the above description is generated after JIBX marshalling.